# Is the following statement a fixed rule?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

If the sum of a series A is greater than the sum of another B, given they have the same domain and that the first value of A is greater than the first value of B.
If these conditions are met, is it a fixed rule that every value of A will be greater than its counterparts value in B. Any exceptions come to mind for this? For example, in the domain of integers from 10 to 20. The series A: 2x and series B: x. The first value at x = 10, A is greater than B. The sum of those integers in the domain given, the sum for A would be greater than the sum of B. Each value of series A is also greater than its counterpart in B. So does the first two conditions imply the third condition or not?

Comment: What do you mean by 'sum of a series A'?

Comment: The sum of all it's values in the given domain. Sorry should've been clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly,

Let $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ & $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_n$ be two convergent series with sums $A$ & $B$ respectively. Here, $a_n, b_n \in D$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $D\subset \mathbb{R}$.
Your question is,

if $A>B$ and $a_1>b_1$ then is it true that $a_n > b_n$ for all $n=2,3,4...$?.

The answer is no. What if I chose two convergent series $A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ & $B=b_1+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} b_n$ with the condition $a_1>b_1$ and $b_n = a_n$ for all $n=2,3,...$.

Clearly $A>B$ but $a_n=b_n$ for all $n=2,3,...$.